# How can I get a icloud PDF file path to base64 string ? Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

how to get pdf file path? and covert pdf file to base64 string

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    if controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.import {
        // This is what it should be
        //            self.txtName.text = String(contentsOfFile: url.path)
       //hear get base64 string
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for `Data`.

Comment: which documentation for Data

Comment: The reference documentation for the `Data` struct.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code for file to base64:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    let fileData = try! Data.init(contentsOf: url)
    let base64String: String = fileData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
}
```